# Database migration to add new column using sequelize-cli don't show any result in postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, database-migration, sequelize-cli

I am trying to add a column using sequelize-cli migration (http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html). This is the structure 
-config/config.json
-migrations
-models
-models/index.js

I am trying to run a migration script which is as follows:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {

  up: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {

    return queryInterface.addColumn('faltus','HelpFlag',Sequelize.INTEGER)

  },

  down: function(queryInterface, Sequelize) {

    return queryInterface.removeColumn('faltus','HelpFlag')

  }

};
```

I am running the script using 'sequelize db:migrate' command. On terminal, the migartion script is successful. 
[MigrationsuccessImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVY1P.png)

But when I check the new column in my postgres database, I can't see any 'HelpFlag' column. I tried to rerun the same script by removing the entry in sequelize-meta.json (store all the migartions). I get 
**error: column "HelpFlag" of relation "faltus" already exists.**

Comment: have you checked that you're connected to the same DB ? Your query should be `...addColumn('faltus', 'HelpFlag', {type: Sequelize.Integer})` . Third parameter is an object: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/query-interface.js~QueryInterface.html#instance-method-addColumn

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Could you please accept my answer then :)

Comment: Answer accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be `...addColumn('faltus', 'HelpFlag', {type: Sequelize.Integer})` . Third parameter is an object